# How to identify my objects in ELKI DBSCAN results?

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

I'm using ELKI GUI to run DBSCAN algorithm. My input is a CSV file. I create a projection as feature selection:

```
-dbc.filter transform.ProjectionFilter -projection NumericalFeatureSelection -projectionfilter.selectedattributes 1,2
```

ELKI gives me some files as clusters. These files contain only projected attributes and other attributes such as *UserId* not exists. How can I identify *UserId* for each object in clusters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is *not* using projection to remove unwanted columns (which will literally *remove* these columns), but instead treat them as *labels*. Because that is what they are, labels.

Usually, the most reliable approach is to include a unique identifier (object label) with each object, if you want to be able to *identify* points afterwards.

In other words, use

```
-parser.labelIndices 0
```

instead of your filter (choose your label columns, of course - assuming your user id is in column 0).